# Cambiar el texto de un boton con on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una tabla la cual me lista datos. Lo que quiero hacer es que al apretar un botón éste me cambie de texto (entre Mostrar y ocultar):

- Cuando le doy un click me oculta los elementos seleccionados y me cambia el texto a mostrar, y
- Cuando le de a mostrar me cambie el texto a ocultar y muestre los elementos.

Éste es mi código, que me oculta los elementos y me los muestra, pero el botón no cambia de texto:

```
if( $("#btnQuitar").on("click",function(){ 
    $('#data-table-default tr.solucionada').toggle(); 
    $("#btnQuitar").text("Mostrar");
else
     $('#data-table-default tr.solucionada').toggle();
     $("#btnQuitar").text("Ocultar");
)
});
```

Comment: creo que tienes problemas con las llaves del condicional

Comment: El código compartido contiene errores de sintaxis que harán que no funcione (ni siquiera para mostrar/ocultar los elementos). Asegúrate de que copias el código que tienes tal cual (a veces al reescribirlo en la pregunta cometemos errores que no tenemos en el código real). Y sería ideal si pudieras añadir el HTML para crear un [mcve] y que podamos ver el problema en la pregunta en sí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, buscas algo como esto.

Al hacer click el ternario recupera uno de los dos textos para que sean colocados en el botón.

```js
$(function(){
   $("#btnCambiar").click(function () {
      /*
         Aquí cambia el elemento, lo dejo comentado para que no falle el snippet
         quita las barras // en tu contexto y debería funcionar
      */
      //$('#data-table-default tr.solucionada').toggle();
      $(this).text(function(i, text){
          return text === "MOSTRAR" ? "OCULTAR" : "MOSTRAR";
      })
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btnCambiar">MOSTRAR</button>
```

Comment: Perfecto , esto era lo que buscaba . gracias:D

Answer (score 0):

Tienes problemas con las llaves de tu condicional.

Un condicional if-else bien construido debe seguir la estructura siguiente:

```
if (condicion) 
{
  codigo 1;
} 
else 
{
  codigo 2;
}
```

**EDICIÓN**

Interpreto que el código que quieres ejecutar entre las llaves es el siguiente para el `if`:

```
$('#data-table-default tr.solucionada').toggle();
$("#btnQuitar").text("Mostrar");
```

Y este otro para el `else`:

```
$('#data-table-default tr.solucionada').toggle();
$("#btnQuitar").text("Ocultar");
```

Comment: Por favor evita enviar saludos o usar firmas en tu respuesta si no añaden relevancia a la solución final