# ¿Para qué sirve el parámetro i, en la función text() de jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Refiriendo a la respuesta del siguiente post: [Cambiar el texto de un boton con on click](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234448/cambiar-el-texto-de-un-boton-con-on-click/234453#234453?newreg=082a2d9be78a43d7b3021ff353b59655)
no entiendo por qué si no se agrega la i, no funciona el código siendo que i no se usa para nada.

```
$(this).text(function(i, text){
        return text === "Ver storage" ? "Ocultar storage" : "Ver storage";
    })
```

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Tu pregunta se responde leyendo la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function). Creo que antes de realizar una pregunta, debes buscar la información, aplicar el resultado y si tienes un problema real, tu pregunta será bienvenida. Saludos

Comment: muchas de las funciones de jQuery que involucran varios elementos exponen el índice ( la posición en la lista ) como primer parámetro, se suele indicar con `i`, o `idx` a veces es útil para condicionar la función definida como callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una interfaz del método [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) a partir de la versión 1.4, y se debe usar tal como fue definida, por tanto, no se puede modificar los parámetros cuando la uses.

El parámetro *i* te permitirá conocer el indice del texto encontrado, pero si no necesitas esta información simplemente no la usas.

Answer (score 1):

Según veo en la API de [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function), ese método ejecutará la función enviando dos parámetros, indice y texto, en ese orden, que los uses o no es cosa tuya, si solo capturas un parámetro, será el primero que envía (el indice), así que si quieres usar el segundo, deber capturarlo en segundo lugar, aunque no quieras usar el primero.